# Mysql query with view formation?

Tags: mysql, join, view

I have tables in db with name

> inquiry,inquiry_category,contact,category

and I made one view to join these two tables. but for one inquiry there can be multiple categories. so in my view,inquiry record get repeated for each category. but i want to make a view that will show inquiry once with category column should be comma separated with multiple categories.

**previously my view is like this**

```
select
  `i`.`id` AS `id`,
  `i`.`comment` AS `comment`,
  `i`.`doi` AS `doi`,
  `i`.`employee_id` AS `employee_id`,
  `i`.`bid` AS `inq_bid`,`i`.`park` AS `park`,
  `cat`.`category` AS `category`,
  `c`.`id` AS `cont_id`,
  `c`.`fname` AS `fname`,
  `c`.`lname` AS `lname`,
  concat(`c`.`fname`,' ',`c`.`lname`,' ',`c`.`mname`) AS `fullname`,
  `c`.`mobile` AS `mobile`,
  `c`.`mobile2` AS `mobile2`,
  `c`.`phone_no` AS `phone_no`,
  `c`.`email` AS `email`,
  `c`.`gender` AS `gender`,
  `c`.`image` AS `image`,
  `c`.`dob` AS `dob`,
  `c`.`parent_id` AS `parent_id`,
  `c`.`relation` AS `relation`,
  `c`.`address` AS `address`,
  `c`.`pincode` AS `pincode`,
  `c`.`city` AS `city`,
  `c`.`park` AS `cont_park`,
  `cg`.`contact_group` AS `contact_group`
from ((((`pf_Papafit_9510`.`contact` `c`
join `pf_Papafit_9510`.`contact_group` `cg`)
join `pf_Papafit_9510`.`category` `cat`)
join `pf_Papafit_9510`.`inquiry` `i`)
join `pf_Papafit_9510`.`inquiry_category` `ic`)
where
  ((`cg`.`id` = `c`.`contact_group_id`)
  and (`c`.`id` = `i`.`contact_id`)
  and (`i`.`id` = `ic`.`inquiry_id`)
  and (`ic`.`category_id` = `cat`.`id`))
```

Comment: What has your question to do with PHP? Also what is exactly your question?

Comment: Read it above @C0dekid

Comment: Use GROUP_CONCAT on the columns you want comma separated, and add an appropriate GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Thank you so much @SloanThrasher